# how to create static field in mysql db select query using codeigniter active records?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In MySQLquery .I can write this

```
SELECT 500 as myValue FROM `myTable` WHERE 1 ;
```

so how to write this in codeigniter active records.

what i have tried

```
$this->db->select("$valas as myValue ");
```

but this gives

```
Unknown column '500' in 'field list'
```

Need solution apart from this

```
     $this->db->query("$valas as myValue ");
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: what your query mean? you want to get the first 500 rows? from dinamic table in query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try passing false as second parameter in select

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or
>   table names with backticks.

```
   $this->db->select("500 as myValue", false);
```